# Ankh svn not appearing in source control for visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

Ankh svn not appearing in source control for visual studio 2013. I have downloaded this with tortoise svn and then browsed to Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in Selection however it does not show up at all. Please help!!

Comment: Downloading it doesn't tell us you actually installed it.  Does Tortoise SVN show up in the Explorer context menu when you right mouse click a folder?

Comment: Hello, yeah both ankh svn and tortoise svn are downloaded and installed and Tortoise SVN does show up in the Explorer context menu when you right mouse click a folder